# While I'm in my praying, can I say Dua in different languages?

Tags: salat, dua, arabic, language

If I don't know the Arabic meaning of a Dua, can I say the Dua in a different language?

Comment: This should help: http://islamqa.info/en/20953

Comment: Of course, Allah understands each and everything if you keep it hidden or speak it loud, be it in any form or language. It's the intention that matters

Answer (score 1):

If the Du'a is within Salah, then I don't think you can translate it into your language.

But, if the Du'a you're making is after the completion of Salah, **Of course Why not?**

1. Yes it is highly suggested that you make Du'a in a language in which you understand *in the beginning*.
2. It is (highly) suggested that you learn the literal meaning of the Arabic words of the Du'a as soon as possible and slowly *start making Du'a in Arabic* understanding what you're saying.

Because the basic definition of Du'a is a way of talking to Allah which I bet you would prefer to do it by understanding the conversation.

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: yeah, it is a true issue as you declared "If the Du'a is within Salah, then I don't think you can translate it into your language.". Shi'a believes like this as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
              In the name of Allah the most compassionate the most merciful
```

Muslims ought to say their prayers in Arabic not in other languages. But according to many of Shia Marjas  (not all of them), (I am not aware of dear Sunni Marja’s), it would be permissible to say your dua in other language during your Qunoot, Marjas such as Ayatollah Khomeini, Khamenei, Bahjat, …  consequently it is better to say the Qunoot in Arabic. As a result, you ought to say your all prayers in Arabic (except what I stated…)

As a suggestion, endeavor to learn the meaning of Salah sentence, it won’t be so hard or taking a lot of your time to learn them. (In order to have a better comprehension from the salah).

---

**Reference**:

[www.farsnews.com](http://www.farsnews.com/newstext.php?nn=13911201001036)

[www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa27660)

Answer (score 0):

Assalam alaikum

Duah (dua/prayer) is something personal between you and your lord, as you are supplicating to Him and asking from him. As long as it is from your heart and you know your place in front of your lord, no one can say what you are doing is wrong unless there is some Islamic law against it. To my knowledge i have never heard of any such ruling that duah should only be read in Arabic, but always think of duah as asking for a favour from your lord. You should however try to learn the Arabic language to try understanding the Quran, which in turn can also help with knowing how to recite duah in Arabic if that is an issue for you :) salaams

Comment: Walaikum-as-salam
In my humble opinion we should never say there is no Islamic ruling on such and such. People of knowledge refrain from doing so and I am not sure where you got that from.

Comment: @SalmanSyed you have a point brother, i shouldnt have said that. I have edited my response, and InShaAllah it is a better response.

Comment: @TashannaChamma, Tis an appropriate advica that you said " try to learn the arabic language to try understanding the quran" / about the question:  As Shia view: you cannot pray in another language because the Prophet did it in Arabic, but only you can offer dua in another language during your Qunut (only) (Qunut considered as a Mustahab practice),