# Sujood, and Salat Tawba

Tags: salat, dua, tawba, language

Can I ask Allah in Salat in Sujood of Dua in my own language? I don't know how to make Duas in Arabic. And one more thing: like this sujood, as you all may have heard of Salat Tawba. Can I perform the prayer every night as to ask Allah for forgiveness, even when I know I haven't done anything, just to repent to him, and to ask Allah for blessings through duas after in hope to make my duniya and aakhira successful?

Comment: See also: "[While I'm in my praying can I say Dua in different languages?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24304/9123)"

Answer (score 1):

> If the worshipper can say du’aa’ well in Arabic, it is not permissible
> for him to make du’aa’ in any other language.
>
> But if the worshipper is unable to make du’aa’ in Arabic, there is no
> reason why he should not make du’aa’ in his own language
>
> Full fatwa: http://islamqa.info/en/20953

About the Tawba every night, you can do it.. And it's something good as in Quran 2:222 :

> إِنَّ اللَّهَ يُحِبُّ التَّوَّابِينَ وَيُحِبُّ الْمُتَطَهِّرِينَ
>
> "Indeed, Allah loves those who are constantly repentant and loves
> those who purify themselves."
>
> Source: http://quran.com/2/222